Retrieving the max 'int64_t'/'uint64_t' value from a NUMERIC column
I have a PostgreSQL database, and I store the maximum value of an int64_t or an uint64_t in a column of the NUMERIC type (I cannot use the BIGINT type as there is no unsigned variant for the uint64_t in PostgreSQL).
Looking at Qt Documentation — Data Types for Qt-supported Database Systems — PostgreSQL Data Types, it seems that NUMERIC is mapped to qreal (= double), which obviously won't be able to hold those values without loss of precision.
Is there a way to remap the default QVariant mapping to something else without modifying the driver? Or is there an alternative way to retrieve such values without casting them to string on the DB side?

If you set the Database's numerical precision policy to QSql::HighPrecision, NUMERIC fields are returned as QStrings.
db.setNumericalPrecisionPolicy(QSql::HighPrecision);

